# constructor with single underscore

Tags: php, magento2

I have below code in model of Magento2 custom module. As I know  constructor can be define using `__construct()` but in below code they used `_construct()`.I want to know the difference between two. Can it be a function ?

```
use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Post extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * Post Abstract Resource Constructor
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('myblog', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: _construct is just a normal function. Probably used for some framework magic

Comment: The one with one underscore is not a constructor i.e. won't be called upon class instantiation.

Comment: ..or its a typo instead of __construct

Comment: They might have created a function called `_construct()` which just calls `__construct()`. But that wouldn't work with `new Post`, as that is only calling `__construct()`.

Comment: I got it but can anyone reply in reference to magento2 ?

Comment: @Qirel  is right

Answer (score 2):

I got answer and mentioning here if someone have any confusion for the same. In reference to Magento2 , single-underscore construct method is a legacy code from Magento 1 and it is called in real _construct method of \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel.

Answer (score 0):

`_construct` is not constructor its a method like other methods. Where `__construct` is the default constructor.

**For details [(__construct and _construct)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95158/what-is-construct-and-construct-in-magento2)**

Answer (score 0):

Single underscore construct (`_construct`) is used to avoid overriding the actual constructor with double underscore (`__construct`).

Example: `vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php`

```
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        /**
         * Please override this one instead of overriding real __construct constructor
         */
        $this->_construct();
    }

    /**
     * Resource initialization
     *
     * @return void
     */
    abstract protected function _construct();
```

Related question with more answers: [Why does Magento have _construct and __construct methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8706352/327862)